# Icon not changing from API data

Tags: javascript, html

[image: SCREENSHOT OF PAGE WITH ORANGE ICON]

I am trying to code along a weather app, it takes all the information from the openweather API. I am trying to retrieve icon based on the location's weather, icon is not changing.

I have given a class to div element which has an image. in the script i am selecting the same class to change the Innertext of that div.

JAVASCRIPT CODE.

```
const apikey = "5d5c5bd6dae4ea02dafca9dc14889b45";

const weatherData = document.getElementById('weather-data')
const cityInput = document.getElementById('city-input');

const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const cityValue = cityInput.value;

    getWeatherData(cityValue);



})

async function getWeatherData(cityValue){
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityValue}&appid=${apikey}&units=metric`)

        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("network error was not ok")
        }

        const data = await response.json();

        console.log(data)

        const temperature = Math.round(data.main.temp)
        const description = data.weather[0].description
        const icon = data.weather[0].icon
        

        const details = [`Feels like: ${Math.round(data.main.feels_like)}`, `Humidity: ${data.main.humidity}`,
        `wind speed: ${data.wind.speed}`]

        weatherData.querySelector('.icon').innerHTML = `<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png" alt="icon" />`;

        console.log(icon)
    }catch (error){

    }

}
```

HTML CODE

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Weather App</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="city-input" placeholder="Enter city" />
        <input type="submit" value="Get Weather" />
      </form>
      <div id="weather-data">
        <div class="icon">
          <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d.png" alt="icon" />
        </div>
        <div class="temperature">22°C</div>
        <div class="description">Sunny</div>
        <div class="details">
          <div>Feels like: 23°C</div>
          <div>Humidity: 40%°C</div>
          <div>Wind Speed: 5 m/s</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tested your code locally, and it seems like the icon is working properly. Did you see any errors from your browser's dev tools?